# Fast value access from string-based key path

Tags: java, performance, coldfusion, hashmap

I'm currently implementing a generic model for pivot-like data visualization in ColdFusion 9.

I'm not interested in supporting multiple measures and the model exposes a `numeric valueAt(string colKey, string rowKey)` function that can be called by a view in order to retrieve the resulting aggregation of a measure based on column and row dimensions.

For example, with the data set below, if the measure was `AVG(Age)` and the column dimension `Rank`, then `model.valueOf('3', '')` would return `2.33`.

```
Wine  Age Rank
WineA 3    3
WineB 4    2
WineC 2    3
WineD 2    3
```

Now, the data structure that naturally came to my mind was to use a `java.util.HashMap` to store the computed data, using a combination of column and row values converted to string as keys. This means that depending on the data set, I might potentially have a very large number of keys that will start with the same prefix.

I purposely created a large data set (1 million entries) with multiple strings having the same prefix and checked the percentage of bucket collisions I would get using the default java `String.hashCode()` algorithm and [MurmurHash3](https://github.com/yonik/java_util/blob/master/src/util/hash/MurmurHash3.java).

Here's how I build the data set sample:

```
<cfset maxItemsCount = 1000000>
<cfset tokens = ['test', 'one', 'two', 'tree', 'four', 'five']>
<cfset tokensLen = arrayLen(tokens)>
<cfset items = []>
<cfset loopCount = 1>

<cfloop condition="arrayLen(items) lt maxItemsCount">
    <cfset item = ''>

    <cfloop from="1" to="#tokensLen#" index="i">
        <cfset item = listAppend(item, tokens[i] & loopCount, '_')>
        <cfset arrayAppend(items, item)>
    </cfloop>

    <cfset ++loopCount>
</cfloop>
```

With an array initialized to *`2 * entries count`*, I got **27%** collisions with **`String.hashCode()`** and **22%** for **Murmur**. It took around 2580 milliseconds with `java.util.HashMap` only to store and retrieve keys once.

I'm looking for ideas on how to improve performance, whether by using a different data structures (perhaps nested hash maps?) or find a way to reduce the number of collisions **without compromising the API signature**?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this essentially the purpose of using a database? Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @ControlAltDel If a `HashMap` is too slow, a database will be even much slower. It makes no sense.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Working with per-aggregated data, while reducing flexibility will certainly improve performance, but the issue I describe still exists. Once you have your cube in memory, how will you honor the API? You can't hit the DB for every question the model gets asked. You could order your cube in the exact order in which the view will display it, but then it will be very hard to accomodate other kind of views.

Answer (score 1):

With a million entries, there will always be some collisions (unless your array is much longer than 1e12 entries :D). I guess that MurmurHash makes a perfect job here, but you could try MD5 for comparison (which is sort of guaranteed to do a perfect job).

> Now, the data structure that naturally came to my mind was to use a java.util.HashMap to store the computed data, using a combination of column and row values converted to string as keys. This means that depending on the data set, I might potentially have a very large number of keys that will start with the same prefix.

You're concatenating Strings and so producing quite some garbage. It may be better to create a

```
@Value static class Key {
    private final String row;
    private final String column;
}
```

as a key for your `HashMap`, where `@Value` is a [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Value.html) annotation generating all the boring stuff like `equals`, `hashCode` and the constructor.

You can do easily without Lombok and even a bit better:

```
static class Key {
    Key(String row, String column) {
         // Do NOT use 31 as a multiplier as it increases the number of collisions!
         // Try Murmur, too.
         hashCode = row.hashCode() + 113 * column.hashCode();
         this.row = row;
         this.column = column;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return hashCode;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Key)) return false;
        Key that = (Key) o;
        // Check hashCode first.
        if (this.hashCode != that.hashCode) return false;
        if (!this.row.equals(that.row)) return false;
        if (!this.column.equals(that.column)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    private final int hashCode;
    private final String row;
    private final String column;
}
```